# Greedy Algorithm, Fewest overlaps

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Hi I need help doing this problem. I've been working on it for like 2 hours now and I'm no where. I'm literally about to throw my computer. I've watched youtube videos, reread my notes. The homework is due tomorrow and I don't have this done yet and I'm freaking out!

This is the question:

Show that a greedy algorithm that schedules talks in a lecture
hall, as described in Example 7, by selecting at each
step the talk that overlaps the fewest other talks, does not
always produce an optimal schedule.

Comment: I think I might have solved it myself. If the algorithm is programmed to pick the fewest conflicts, it will do just that. It will pick the set of the fewest conflicts regardless of whether or not that set includes the most talks. I drew a stupid diagram. I think that answer is right. If it isn't let me know.

Comment: You omitted Example 7

Answer (score 1):

You need to show the whole problem-we don't have access to Example 7.  What is the criterion for "optimum"?  Is it the most talks scheduled without overlap, the highest utilization of the hall, or what?  You are probably expected to show a list of talks, show what the greedy algorithm produces, and show a better solution (according to the criterion for optimum).  Do the talks come with times they have to be given, or are you setting that. This can come from the order you consider the talks-you might scatter a few at various times of the day, preventing many others from being scheduled.  If the talks cannot be moved in time, you might schedule a whole batch from the hour to hour plus 5 minutes (only 5 min long), while you have a bunch of hour talks that don't fit any more.  If you had scheduled the hours first, you would use the hall all day.

Comment: Suppose we have a group of proposed talks with preset start and end times. Devise a greedy algorithm to schedule as many of these talks as possible in a lecture hall, under the assumptions
that once a talk starts, it continues until it ends, no two talks can proceed at the same time, and a talk can begin at the same time another one ends.